# padding in bootstrap using container fluid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

can anyone help me find a bug in bootstrap container fluid which i just need to add some padding but not working
the code only works when we use

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 3% 15% !important;
}
```

if we remove !important it is not working do you know the reason

i will share  the code below

```
<body>
        <section id="title">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Nav Bar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
                    <button
                        class="navbar-toggler"
                        type="button"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    >
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <!-- Title -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>

                        <button type="button">Download</button>
                        <button type="button">Download</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

the  css code is

```
#title {
    background-color: #ff4c78;
}
.container-fluid {
    padding: 3% 15%;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Where are you loading your CSS in relationship to the Bootstrap CSS? You should be loading it afterwards. The styles for `container` are padding on the left and right at 15px, without !important, so your CSS should override Bootstrap, so long as your CSS comes last.

Comment: This is a question of specificity. Only the most specific CSS definition will be applied to an element. The keyword `!important` enforces a certain style and overrides all other definitions. You can read up on CSS specificity here for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thank you :) it actually helped

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you've placed the link to your own custom style sheet or defined custom CSS styles inside the `<style>` tag **before** linking the style sheet of Bootstrap. The browser follows a top-down approach while rendering the pages and so any CSS styles that share the same name (in your case: *.container-fluid*) with the style of another style sheet, then your custom CSS  styles will be overwritten by the styles in the last style sheet.

**Solution:** Place the link to your custom style sheet after linking all the other style sheets like that of Bootstrap, Font Awesome, etc.

If you could include the code that you put in between the `<head>` tag, I could confirm this.

P.S. I see you're doing the TinDog project so you're probably following Angela Yu's course. Here's the GitHub link to [my code](https://github.com/AnubhavTalukdar/TinDog) for reference.

Comment: @VaishnavVOM If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept the answer for further references.